# User is not prompted on reset of the game

Tags: javascript

I have added a function the start of app.js where i added a function promptUser which I want to be called every time when the health bars gets less then zero and the game is reset.

But on reset I am not getting prompt - Any idea or help?

```
let chosenMaxLife; let currentMonsterHealth;
let currentPlayerHealth;
let hasBonusLife = true;
function promptUser() {
const enteredValue = prompt('Maximum life of you and Monster is', '100');
chosenMaxLife = parseInt(enteredValue);

if (isNaN(enteredValue)) {
    chosenMaxLife = 100;
}
currentMonsterHealth = chosenMaxLife;
currentPlayerHealth = chosenMaxLife;

adjustHealthBars(chosenMaxLife);
resetGameAgain();
}
attackBtn.addEventListener('click', attackHandler);
```

Comment: You are declaring the variables inside the function, and accessing them outside it.

Comment: Your `currentMonsterHealth` and `currentPlayerHealth` variables are declared within the scope of the `promptUser()` function. This means they are not availabe outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variables in global scope. You were declaring them inside the function, so they are not accessible outside the function.

```
const Attack_Value = 10;
const monster_attack_value = 12;
const strong_attack_value = 28;
const player_healValue = 20;

let currentMonsterHealth;
let currentPlayerHealth;

function promptUser() {
    const enteredValue = prompt('Maximum life of you and Monster is', '100');
    let chosenMaxLife = parseInt(enteredValue);
 
    if (isNaN(enteredValue)) {
        chosenMaxLife = 100;
    }
    currentMonsterHealth = chosenMaxLife;
    currentPlayerHealth = chosenMaxLife;
    let hasBonusLife = true;    //You need to declare it in global scope as well, depending on usage. 
}
 
if (currentMonsterHealth <= 0 || currentPlayerHealth <= 0) {
        reset();
        promptUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: basically my promptUser function is just ignored even without any logic i put it at the start of the code.

Comment: Haven't you forgot to call the function??

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is resolved. Basically while i am learning i had a function but i never called it anywhere.